# How to hide and show content under a bar of links?

Tags: javascript, css, hide, visibility, show

How do you make a set of links behave like buttons, when one is pressed, it shows some hidden content and when another is pressed it hides the previous content and shows some other content? The first link has to be clicked by default to show the first set of hidden content.

Here's my fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/sr1fqt4n/

I have tried toggle visibility with the following script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function toggle_visibility(id) {
       var e = document.getElementById(id);
       if(e.style.display == 'block')
          e.style.display = 'none';
       else
          e.style.display = 'block';
    }
</script>
```

The problem is that the content of the first link does not show by default and none of the content hides when another link is being clicked. Also, the links does not behave like a button.

The desired result would look like what they have on section 2 分集剧情: https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E6%9D%A5%E8%87%AA%E6%98%9F%E6%98%9F%E7%9A%84%E4%BD%A0/12029711

Comment: [tag:java] question tag removed as it is not appropriate for this question

Answer (score 0):

You need to make multi tabs, there is no need to use the `<a>` tag in this situation you can easily use [a plugin like this](https://www.jqueryscript.net/other/Nested-Tabs-Plugin-jQuery-multiTabs.html)

but if you insist on coding your way into it try a css active class as a flag to which tab and content you want to be visible

Answer (score 0):

Your event handler is only applied to each of the a href on each click. Therefore the event handler is only activated on the element that is clicked and does not affect the other elements as the other elements do not have an event happening to them.

Do you need to use your own code? Or like what Aras mention, there are many plugins available. Both bootstrap and jquery (and whatever library) have solutions for tab panels.

And an `<a>` tag is used to define a hyperlink. A `<button>` or `<div>` tag might be more suitable.

But if you need a vanilla JS solution, here is a pen with code that sets default. Basically, you need a for loop to control the toggle.   https://codepen.io/Ghandour/pen/LjpXPx?editors=1010

```
  for (i = 0; i < tabButton.length; i++) {
    tabContent[i].style.display = 'none';
    tabButton[i].classList.remove('active');
}
```

Will be happy to explain if there are any queries on the code.

Answer (score 0):

- Found [Captain Anonymous's Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qbAdG) and remodified it, check demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Hanasaku_Melody/d8t9jLuw/)
- More example on my [blog](http://hanasakumelody.com/en/a-korean-odyssey/#quotes)

```
    <div class="pagination-bar">
    <div class="pagination-btn">
    <a class="part1">1</a>
    <a class="part2">2</a>
    <a class="part3">3</a>
    <a class="part4">4</a>
    <a class="part5">5</a>
    </div>
    </div>
  


    <div class="content-canvas">


    <ul class="part1">

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Velit euismod in pellentesque massa placerat duis ultricies. Ornare massa eget egestas purus viverra accumsan. Dictumst quisque sagittis purus sit. Elementum facilisis leo vel fringilla est ullamcorper. Arcu odio ut sem nulla pharetra diam sit. Sed vulputate odio ut enim. Non diam phasellus vestibulum lorem. Nunc vel risus commodo viverra maecenas. Morbi tempus iaculis urna id volutpat lacus laoreet non. Morbi tristique senectus et netus. Massa sed elementum tempus egestas sed. Orci dapibus ultrices in iaculis. Malesuada bibendum arcu vitae elementum. Nisl vel pretium lectus quam id leo in vitae turpis.</p>

    </ul>


    <ul class="part2">

    <p>Sit amet nisl purus in mollis. Convallis aenean et tortor at risus. Morbi quis commodo odio aenean sed. Non diam phasellus vestibulum lorem sed risus ultricies. Nam libero justo laoreet sit. Arcu felis bibendum ut tristique et egestas quis ipsum suspendisse. Parturient montes nascetur ridiculus mus mauris vitae. Feugiat pretium nibh ipsum consequat nisl. Pellentesque id nibh tortor id aliquet. Pharetra pharetra massa massa ultricies. Eu sem integer vitae justo eget magna fermentum.</p>

    </ul>


    <ul class="part3">

    <p>Dolor purus non enim praesent elementum facilisis leo vel. Aliquam eleifend mi in nulla posuere sollicitudin aliquam ultrices sagittis. Nec nam aliquam sem et tortor. Viverra suspendisse potenti nullam ac. Vel orci porta non pulvinar neque laoreet suspendisse interdum consectetur. Posuere urna nec tincidunt praesent semper feugiat nibh sed. At consectetur lorem donec massa sapien faucibus et. Fermentum odio eu feugiat pretium nibh. Nullam non nisi est sit amet facilisis magna. Suscipit tellus mauris a diam. Arcu odio ut sem nulla pharetra. Ullamcorper malesuada proin libero nunc. Integer malesuada nunc vel risus. Eu mi bibendum neque egestas congue quisque.</p>

    </ul>


    <ul class="part4">

    <p>Bibendum ut tristique et egestas quis ipsum suspendisse ultrices gravida. Aliquet lectus proin nibh nisl condimentum id venenatis a. Fames ac turpis egestas sed tempus. Nisl vel pretium lectus quam id leo in vitae. Fringilla phasellus faucibus scelerisque eleifend. Ut diam quam nulla porttitor massa. Duis convallis convallis tellus id interdum. Sed vulputate mi sit amet. Commodo viverra maecenas accumsan lacus vel facilisis volutpat est. Nunc mi ipsum faucibus vitae aliquet nec ullamcorper sit. Pretium quam vulputate dignissim suspendisse in. Ipsum suspendisse ultrices gravida dictum fusce. Amet cursus sit amet dictum sit.</p>

    </ul>


    <ul class="part5">

    <p>Senectus et netus et malesuada. Magnis dis parturient montes nascetur. Et ultrices neque ornare aenean. Sed vulputate mi sit amet mauris commodo. Praesent tristique magna sit amet purus gravida quis blandit turpis. Eget lorem dolor sed viverra. Sit amet aliquam id diam. Viverra mauris in aliquam sem fringilla ut morbi. Id cursus metus aliquam eleifend mi in nulla. Viverra accumsan in nisl nisi scelerisque eu ultrices. Tincidunt tortor aliquam nulla facilisi cras fermentum odio. Et leo duis ut diam quam. Ut etiam sit amet nisl purus in mollis nunc. Donec pretium vulputate sapien nec sagittis.</p>

    </ul>



    </div>
```

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.content-canvas').find('ul').hide();
    $('.content-canvas ul:first-child').show();
    $('.pagination-btn a:first-child').addClass('current');
    $('.pagination-btn').find('a').click(function(){
    $('.pagination-btn').find('a').removeClass('current');
    var currentclass=$(this).attr('class');  
    $(this).addClass('current');

    $('.content-canvas').find('ul').each(function(){
    if($(this).attr('class')==currentclass)
    {
    $('.content-canvas').find('ul').hide();
    $(this).show();
    }
    else
    {
     $(this).hide();
    }
    });
    });
    });
```

```
    .current{
    background: #23a1ba;
    color: #fff!important;
    border: 1px solid #23a1ba!important;
    cursor: default!important;
    }

    .pagination-bar {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 0 25px 0;
    }

    .pagination-btn {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
    }

    .pagination-btn a{
    border: 1px solid #DCDCDC;
    border-radius: 4px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 10px 5px 0 0;
    color: #333;
    width: 70px;
    padding: 2px 0 2px 0;
    }

    .pagination-btn a:hover {
    border: 1px solid #23a1ba;
    color: #23a1ba;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    }

    .content-canvas ul{
    padding: 30px;
    color: black;
    background: #eaf8fb;
    border-radius: 8px;
    }




    @media screen and (max-width: 713px) {
    .pagination-btn {
    text-align: center;
    }
    }
```